# Anchor and button not clickable within React modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-dom

I'm trying to use ReactDOM.createPortal to have a global modal that can be opened from anywhere in the React app.  The modal opens and displays correctly.  The problem is that the  and  elements within the modal are not clickable.

I don't mean their onClick functions aren't working, I mean you literally cannot click them at all.  The mouse doesn't change to pointer for either the anchor or the button.  Both elements render as shown below but neither one reacts to a mouse click.  The goal is for an anchor or button to within the modal to close it.

[image]

Since I could not get either the anchor or the button to register clicks I decided to attach the click event to the overlay div that sits behind the modal dialog div and masks the rest of the page.  This does work, however it works too well.  Clicking anywhere within the modal dialog also triggers this click event.

Modal.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './Modal.css';
export default function Modal(props:any){
    const handleCloseClick = () => {
        props.onClose();
    };

    const modalContent = (
        <div className="modal-overlay" onClick={handleCloseClick}>
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <span>{props.title}</span>
                    <a href="#" onClick={handleCloseClick}>X</a>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal content goes here</p>
                    <button>TEST</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(modalContent, document.body as Element);
}
```

Modal.css

```
.modal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 99;
}

.modal-dialog {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

.modal-body {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.modal-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

RootLayout.tsx where the Open Modal button lives and the state of the modal's visibility is controlled.

```
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth, UseLogin, UseLogout } from '../authentication.context';
import Login from './Login';
import './RootLayout.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
export default function RootLayout(props: any) {
    const { state, dispatch } = useAuth();
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        const actions = UseLogout();
        dispatch(actions);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (state) {
            console.log('state in RootLayout:');
            console.log(state);
        }
    }, [state]);

    if (state && state.isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <div className='h-100'>
                <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-md border border-bottom'>
                    <div className='container-fluid'>
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">JOC Dashboard</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className='nav-link active' to="/">Home</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div className='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
                                {state.user &&
                                    <div className='me-3'>Logged in as {state.user.full_name}</div>
                                }

                                <div className=''>
                                    <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleLogout}>LOGOUT</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div id="root-layout-container" className='container-fluid'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-lg-2'>
                            <div className='d-flex flex-column'>
                                <button onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)}>Open Modal</button>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-lg-10'>
                            <Outlet/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {modalVisible &&
                    <Modal title="Title" onClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}/>
                }
            </div>
            
                
        )
    }

    return (
        <div id="root-layout-container" className='container-fluid h-100'>
            {state && !state.isAuthenticated &&
                <Login />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've checked z-index on all the modal divs and I can't see anything that would be laying over top of the anchor or button, but maybe I'm missing it.  What else could cause these elements to not even be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the class names I'm using.  I think one or more of them collide with class names in other dependencies.  This app uses Bootstrap 5 so that could be it.  Everything started working as expected after changing these class names:

- .modal-overlay
- .modal-dialog
- .modal-header
- .modal-body

To these:

- .main-modal__overlay
- .main-modal__dialog
- .main-modal__header
- .main-modal__body